# How to return server not found for domain but allow sub directory to show normally

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

Most all are typically find a way to "not" show can't connect to server browser errors, where is I'm interested in showing it.

I have a domain example.com for a YOURLS link shortener. The homepage shows a 403 Forbidden Nginx notice. The example.com/admin shows the working admin site. This will not be publicly facing and if someone goes to example.com should show can't connect to server, so people do not know that site exists (yes, they can do a whois or dns lookup but not worried about that).

I could change the nginx server root to be a random location and it would show the desired error but then example.com/admin wouldn't work. Is there any easy fix? In the nginx config there is a line: `try_files $uri $uri/ /yourls-loader.php$is_args$args;`

Is there a change I can make there to stop example.com from showing anything but allow example.com/admin to still work? Also yes, I could put a blank index.html but that would show a white page where is looking to show the standard browser error you see if you enter a domain that doesn't have a website.

There maybe a name for this, but not sure how to describe it thus have beemn unable to find a solution to this presumably easy problem.

Comment: Sorry could you let me know if there was a better Stackoverflow suited for this nginx config on ubuntu server question? Researched first and SO seemed to be the best fit. Ultimately the answer was it's not technically possible but one solution proved helpful and quite close to the desired result and imagine many will find useful who wish to have no site should for the primary domain but show for subdomains (The yourls example is just a particular use case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could very well return a 444 (close connection) when the domain is called at it's root.

something like the following would close connection at the source

```
location = / {
    return 444;
}
```

It would still allow for a /admin location block to be served without problems.

444 is a nginx only internal code that effectively closes connection and forces displaying 'nothing'. I suggest you try it with a test block like

```
location = /444test {
    return 444;
    access_log off;
}
```

and see for yourself.

Comment: This is by far the closest to what I'm after. Unfortunately, it causes a different error in the browser, "This page isn't working" vs "This site can't be reached" which is the desired error, since that is what would show for any site that doesn't exist. From what I've heard it sounds like this isn't possible, since there doesn't appear to be an error code  that will show that. Assuming there are no other work arounds will mark this as the most correct since unlike the others at least its much similar to the desired browser error formatting. Thank you!

Comment: Well, since the site CAN actually be reached, we can’t fool a browser into saying the server/site can’t be reached. Your alternative would be, to achieve what you desire, to set a non existing dns on the root domain and use a subdomain for admin - something dark that only admins would know about.

Comment: You could also try a redirect, on the root domain, to something that you know and are certain will not respond. instead of returning a 444, a 302 (make it 301 when you are certain, permanent loves to stick into your cache for way too long) to a non responding ip address

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [HTTP 410 Gone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410) for such cases :)

You can use something like this:

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        return 403;
    }
    location /admin {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /yourls-loader.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # your fastcgi or backend config for PHP scripts here
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that end up showing an actual error page with for instance 410 gone on it, vs showing the desired browser default for server not found? Such as when you typing in fkdsjfkdsfkdsfkdshfjkd . com?

Comment: Yes it would. I don't think it is possible at all to achive the same result as for non-existient site with nginx config. But you can try to use nginx special 444 return code (close connection without response), it will make browser to show "Page unavailable ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error.

Answer (score 0):

You can show your custom error page like this:

In the location `/var/www/error/` create a `custom_403.html` file (where you can show your own error) and then show it with the following code :

```
server { 
   ... 
   error_page 403 /custom_403.html;
   location = /custom_403.html { 
         root /var/www/error/; 
         internal; 
   }
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mention showing a custom error page. Just wanted to make sure you saw I'm not interested in showing a custom error page. Rather I wish for the browser to show the default server not found if viewing example.com, but show normally if viewing example.com/admin.

Comment: Try this: `error_page 403 = @show_error; location @show_error{ return 404; }`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Won't that simply show a 404 error and not show a default server not found? And I don't see logic in that line making sure that /admin still loads normally unless I'm missing something? To clarify for my domain example.com. If a person goes to it want to show the same thing you'd see if you go to fjdksfhjdksfhjkdhfjdhsjfk.com but if you go to example.com/admin it would show that app normally. Just to confirm, are you sure the above code accomplishes that?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot disable nginx error response and replace it with browser's own error page. You need to create a custom error page.

Comment: If you want to update your response then to my question as, it's not currently possible to have the main domain show no server response while allowing a sub directory to server normally... then I can wait to see if anyone says anything to the contrary and if not can accept that as the answer. Thanks!